# Ignite Deb Package Mirrors

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ignite, deb

https://apache.org/dist/ignite/deb is down due to the sunset of bintray. I need a deb package of ignite 2.9.0-1 and was hoping there was a mirror somewhere or if there was someway to get the deb off a machine that already has ignite running.

All ignite documentation still points to Bintray

// https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/deb

I tried to use ignite's deb package.sh to build my own deb but I'm a little out of my element there and got the following error: [ERROR] RPM for converting to DEB not found

Hoping someone has a mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache moved Ignite's repositories here:

- https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/ignite-deb/
- https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/ignite-rpm/